# Gödel's incompleteness theorem: if the statement is unprovable then how did we prove its true?

Tags: logic, computability, incompleteness

The proof for Gödel's incompleteness theorem shows that for any formal system $F$ strong enough to do arithmetic, there exists a statement $P$ that is unprovable in $F$ yet $P$ is true.

Let $F$ be the system we used to prove this theorem.

Then $P$ is unprovable in $F$ yet we proved it is true in $F$.

Contradiction.

Am I saying something wrong? Is $F$ forced to be inconsistent?

Comment: P is true according to the "natural interpretation" of it. See [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/): G's sentence asserts its own unprovability (in the system F). But G's Th shows that it is unprovable in F; thus, the G's sentence "speaks the true".

Comment: What you just said is a proof for G' s sentence. But you said it is unprovable

Comment: There are others "unprovable result" following G's Th; see [Paris–Harrington theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem): "this theorem states that a certain combinatorial principle in Ramsey theory, namely the strengthened finite Ramsey theorem, is true, but not provable in Peano arithmetic." Again, the result is "true" because it is provable in a  strengthened theory then PA: the proof can be carried out in second-order arithmetic.

Comment: Unprovable **in** F; the sentence P is provable in a "strengthened" theory, like F+P.

Comment: The underlying assumption is that $\mathsf{PA}$ is *sound*, meaning that $\mathbb N\models\mathsf{PA}$. To say that $P$ is true is simply to claim that $\mathbb N\models P$. A different matter is how to verify the latter. Any proof of it by necessity takes place in a stronger theory than $\mathsf{PA}$.

Comment: Mauro ALLEGRANZA , but we didn't have P as an axiom, we proved it. Thus we are working in F.

Comment: As I have said, let F be the system of logic we use to prove godels theorem. Thus in F we showed that godels theorem holds. Thus P is true yet unprovable in F. Now what we have done is to provide a proof in F that P is true. Contradiction

Comment: " let F be the system of logic we use to prove godels theorem." NO; the G's Th is **about** the system $F$ (e.g. first-order [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic): usually abbreviated $\mathsf {PA}$) and it asserts that $P$ is unprovable in F. G's Th itself is proved **in** a meta-theory that we can formalize in some new formal system.

Comment: Let F be that new formal system. I don't understand why F can't talk about itself? Why do you have to have a bigger system? Godels theorem is proved In a certain system L and shows that for any F (strong enough to do arithematic) P is true and unprovable. So substitute F=L

Comment: You found a contradiction.  You have to look at the assumptions you made, because, as a whole, they are inconsistent.  You assumed that $F$ is the system in which you proved Goedel's Theorem.  So, you have to accept that either $F$ does not satisfy the premises of the theorem (e.g., it's inconsistent or not powerful enough), or that indeed $F$ is not the system in which you proved the theorem.  Of course, you may also argue that there's an error in the theorem, but you cannot claim that there must be one because you found a contradiction.

Comment: No, the theorem requires the system F to be consistent. Otherwise, P (and anything else) is provable in F. But (from the second incompleteness theorem) F itself cannot prove that F is consistent. Gödel assumes that $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent, since he assumes that it has a model (namely, $\mathbb N$). This assumption puts the argument outside of $\mathsf{PA}$. (And yes, Gödel does not mention $\mathsf{PA}$ explicitly, because he argues in terms of the system of Russell and Whitehead's *Principia*. The same remarks apply.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misreading - choosing a system F at the beginning and then re-choosing F to be something else later
.

Comment: @CarlMummert has a good explanation for what's wrong with this problem. Related Numberphile video that explains exactly why this happens: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4ndIDcDSGc

Comment: Actually I posted this question after i watched the video, and couldn't understand why you have to prove Godel's theorem in a higher logic. seemed to me that F could talk about itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are missing a key hypothesis in the statement of Gödel's incompleteness theorem.  You wrote in a comment:

> Godels theorem is proved In a certain system L and shows that for any F (strong enough to do arithematic) P is true and unprovable.

This is incorrect.  Gödel's theorem is proved in a certain system $L$ and says the following.  Suppose $F$ is a formal system which is strong enough to do arithmetic **and consistent** (that is, it does not prove a contradiction).  Then a certain arithmetic statement $P$ (which is defined in terms of the system $F$) is true but is not provable in $F$.

Now you want to substitute $L$ for $F$.  That's fine, but in order to apply Gödel's theorem, you need to know that the hypotheses are satisfied.  That is, you need to know that $L$ is strong enough to do arithmetic and that $L$ is consistent.  Verifying the first hypothesis is easy, but verifying the second hypothesis is not easy at all.  Before you can carry out your argument, you need to prove (within the system $L$) that $L$ is consistent.

In fact, your argument does work (modulo some details that are technical but important) if $L$ could prove that $L$ is consistent, and would reach a contradiction.  So actually, your argument shows that if $L$ can prove that $L$ is consistent, there is a contradiction in $L$ (and so $L$ is not actually consistent at all!).  This is exactly the statement of Gödel's *second* incompleteness theorem, which says that no consistent formal system strong enough to do arithmetic can prove its own consistency.

(The technical details: to reach a contradiction, you need to not prove $P$ within $L$, but prove that $L$ proves $P$ within $L$.  That is, $L$ needs know not just that $P$ is true, but that $L$ can prove $P$, since this is what contradicts the fact that $P$ is unprovable in $L$.  The fact that if $L$ proves $P$ then $L$ proves that it proves $P$ is a consequence of being able to do arithmetic in $L$.

These details are important because in order to prove that $L$ proves $P$, you have to actually have an honest proof of $P$ within $L$.  If you have a proof within $L$ that $L$ is consistent, then you get such an honest proof of $P$ from Gödel.  But if you just assume for a contradiction that $L$ is consistent, you don't get such a proof and so you cannot conclude that $L$ proves $P$; instead you only know that $P$ is true.  So you can't reach a contradiction: there is no contradiction between the two statements "$P$ is true" and "$L$ cannot prove $P$".)

Comment: Actually, the argument, as sketched, would reach a contradiction only if one assumes soundness of L (that is, that L only proves true statements). This is stronger than mere consistency. (By the way, Gödel's result does not require this assumption, but his original proof does.)

Comment: I don't think so (and I think you may be misinterpreting OP's argument, or maybe I am).  If $L$ proves its consistency, then $L$ proves $P$ and $L$ proves that $L$ does not prove $P$.  But if $L$ proves $P$, then $L$ proves that $L$ proves $P$.  So $L$ proves both that $L$ proves $P$ and that $L$ does not prove $P$, which is a contradiction.  (Of course, OP did not make explicit the step where $L$ proves that $L$ can prove $P$, but I think this version is closer to what they had in mind than any argument using soundness.)

Comment: "Verifying the first hypothesis is easy, but verifying the second hypothesis is not easy at all"

I don't want to verify it, i'm simply saying: if L is inconsistent we are done, if L is consistent then my reasoning shows that it is inconsistent. therefor L is inconsistent.

Comment: Ah, but there's a difference between $L$ being consistent and $L$ _proving_ that $L$ is consistent.  It is possible that $L$ is consistent, but $L$ cannot prove that $L$ is consistent.

Comment: let me digest your answer a bit more before i reply. haha

Comment: In particular, it seems you have the following argument in mind (working within $L$).  Suppose (for a contradiction) that $L$ is consistent.  Then by Gödel, $P$ is true and $L$ cannot prove $P$.  Therefore $L$ proves $P$ and $L$ cannot prove $P$, which is a contradiction.  The error in this argument is that "Therefore $L$ proves $P$" does not follow.  Within this argument we know that $P$ is true, but we don't know that $L$ proves $P$.

Comment: If we had an actual honest proof of $P$ within $L$ (rather than a conclusion that $P$ is true as an intermediate step of a proof by contradiction), we could formalize that proof within $L$ to prove that $L$ proves $P$.  This is the "technical details" I mentioned in my answer.  But if we can just deduce $P$ from some assumption within $L$, we can't prove from that assumption that $L$ proves $P$.

Comment: @Eric The OP is not discussing the argument in terms of the Hilbert-Bernays provability conditions (as in your comment), but rather in terms of truth.

Comment: Excellent. You got my point exactly. So you are saying that L proves: L is consistent **implies** P is true, but does not prove: P is true. Am I correct?

Comment: That's right.  And perhaps more importantly for the technical details, if $L$ proves that $L$ is consistent, then $L$ proves that $L$ proves $P$ is true.  But $L$ does not prove the statement "if $L$ is consistent, then $L$ proves $P$ is true".

Comment: Yes. So actually my argument is the second incompleteness theorem?

Comment: Yes, your argument is pretty much just the standard proof of the second incompleteness theorem.

Comment: @EricWofsey No, it is not. The standard (modern) version of the second incompleteness theorem does not discuss truth.

Comment: @EricWofsey Damn, that's deep stuff. Thank you so much for taking the time for clearing my misconception with such clear explanations. Im glad I stumbled upon the second incompleteness theorem proof without reading it.@Andrés E. Caicedo Now for this business about truth, what do you mean 'does not discuss truth ?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: Again, I believe you are misinterpreting OP (and in particular I think you are interpreting their use of the word "true" with a technical meaning that they do not intend).  In any case, even if your interpretation is what they mean, I stand by my assertion that their argument is _pretty much_ the standard proof.

Comment: @EricWofsey Well, "truth" has a technical meaning. The difference between it and provability is essential in the context of the incompleteness theorems. Anyway, the OP seems satisfied, so we can move on.

Answer (score 2):

Not the biggest expert in this, but maybe this helps until the real experts show up.

To prove a statement $\phi$ from (a first-order theory) $F$ means (by the completeness theorem) to show that it holds in *all* models of $F$. However, still without proving $\phi$ from $F$ we can look at some particular model of $F$ (via meta theory) and find that $\phi$ indeed holds there. So we have an external proof of $\phi$ for this specific model.

Now if $\phi$ says "$\phi$ cannot be proven from $F$", then this means that we *need* this meta theory on this specific model to prove $\phi$ and it cannot be done from $F$ alone.

Even another way: we showed that $\phi$ holds in *some* model (externally). Then $\phi$ showed that there are models where it does not hold. So not all models agree. So neither $\phi$ nor $\neg \phi$ can be provable.

Comment: What I'm saying is what if the meta-logic and the normal logic are the same? What if F was the normal system of logic in which we proved godels theorem?

Comment: @user47376 - the issue of G's Th is exactly that the system (not "the logic"), say $F$, and the meta-system cannot be the same. If we use a "sufficiently strong" system (like Peano Arithmetic) that can prove "facts" about formal systems (and thus is suitable as a meta-theory), this kind of system cannot proves "all" that is true. Specifically, a system like $\mathsf {PA}$, when used as a meta-system, cannot prove its own *consistency*. This means that the formal system $\mathsf {PA}$ is in some sense "limited"; it does **not** mean that it is *inconsistent*.

Comment: My reasoning shows that it proves it's own **in**consistency. Why can't they be the same? This is my question.

Comment: @user47376 Something cannot be *true* in $F$, just *provable* from it. And $\phi$ says that it is not. However $\phi$ is either true or false in any model of $F$. There is no contradiction. One the one hand you showed that $\phi$ is true in *some* model. On the other hand you showed that it is *not true* in all models (that's what you call truth)!

Comment: Saying P is true is saying that it is provable in the meta-system, but since they are both F it's a contradiction. What do you mean in all models? I'm talking about a specific F, the one which we use to prove G's Th.

Comment: @user47376 Truth only exists with respect to a model. The meta system *does not* prove the unconditional truth of $P$ (if you belive this, you are wrong), *but* its truth w.r.t. *a model* $M$. This does not imply that it must be provable from $F$.

Comment: Excuse me, but I'm not an expert in the subject and I do not understand the precise meaning of the words you use, specifically: truth and model, and the difference between formal system and model. Also I think I can entirely avoid the use of the word true in my reasoning, all I did was to talk about the probability of godels theorem and godels sentence under F

Comment: @user47376 Ah, I see. That is why one is usually encouraged to specify ones state of knowledge in the question. This however changes everything. I suggest you to first look up the meaning of these term (this is usually assumed when a question on gödels sentences is asked) or ask for clarification in a separate question (do *not* change this question significantly). But first check if such a question has not been asked before. For now I can formulate my answer in this way: the incompleteness theorem *does not* show that $P$ is true. This is were your contradiction breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: In what follows when I say formal system I mean a first-order theory)

Be careful, you are mixing two different concepts namely "provability" and "truth".

Gödel incompleteness theorem (more correctly its generalization, *Rosser's theorem*) says that

> If $F$ is a formal system in which you can interpret arithmetic (which roughly means that you can say what is a number, a zero, a successor, the addition and multiplication and prove the axioms of arithmetic) then it is either inconsistent, hence it proves everything, or it is incomplete (that is there are statement which aren't provable nor disprovable).

In this form of the theorem there is no reference to the concept of truth.

Actually the original Gödel's incompleteness theorem says something different:

> There are statement that are not provable in Peano Arithmetic but are true in the model of the natural numbers $\mathbb N$.

A statement can be *proved in a formal system $F$* but it doesn't make any sense to say that *it is true in $F$*, a statement is either true or false in a given interpretation.

You could *define* that a statement is true in a formal system $F$ if it is true in all its model, that is if it is a logical consequence of the axioms in $F$. Of course by the Gödel's *completeness* theorem that is equivalent to the fact that the statement is provable in $F$, so clearly this is not the correct statement of Gödel incompleteness theorem.

Hope this helps.